# Pitch accent of 止まらないんだ

Tags: pitch-accent

I'm confused on the pitch accent for the phrase 止まらないんだ.

I know that the pitch accent for 止まらない is 平板型 (とまらない{LHHHH}). From my own experience, I think that the accent for 止まらないんだ looks like this とまらないんだ{LHHHLLL}. However, OJAD tells me that the downstep should be at the い position. So, it will look like とまらないんだ{LHHHHLL} instead.

Which one of these pitch accents is the correct one?

Comment: Where does OJAD give the pitch accent for 止まらないんだ ? If you're talking about the Prosody Tutor, then you should be aware that it is sometimes not accurate when particles are copula are included.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about the Prosody Tutor. I see. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

The correct accent is 止まらないんだ{LHHHLLL}. The drop comes from ＼んだ, but it moves back for the vowel. OJAD’s Suzuki-kun is wrong (like it often is).

Comment: Do non-past verbs do this too? ちがう{LHH} -> ちがうんだ{LHLLL}. Heard them be said right after each other and it sounded like that.

Comment: Sometimes the accent can move from う to が there but I’d say it’s less clear cut, you hear both (while you never hear い accented in the phrase here)